# Javascript and Vue.js infinite while loop in async function alternative

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, interpolation

I currently use an async function to interpolate a certain set of elements from the DOM, it currently works great but I can't pass the lint verification for example so I was wondering if anyone knew of a better solutions. Here's my current code:

```
 async mounted() {
    let colorMap = interpolate(['#fffbfb', '#ff4141']);

    let i

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
    while (true) {
      let switchColor = false
      for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        let group = this.blinkingGroup
        if (!switchColor) {
          colorMap = interpolate(['#ff4141', '#fffbfb']);
        } else {
          colorMap = interpolate(['#fffbfb', '#ff4141']);
        }
        group.forEach(value => {
          try {
            value.dom.style.stroke = colorMap(i * 0.01)
          } catch (e) {
            //console.log(e)
          }
        })
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10));
        switchColor = true

      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: As mentioned in the comments, requestAnimationFrame is a better fit here:

Why better?

- The browser can optimize it, so animations will be smoother
- Animations in inactive tabs will stop, allowing the CPU to chill
- More battery-friendly

you can read more about RequestAnimationFrame [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/)

---

old
you can use setInterval instead of while(true)

> setInterval(function, milliseconds)

Comment: requestAnimationFrame would be even more appropriate, as this is a blinking animation. setInterval may cause issues when multiple of these components have been loaded. Worth noting that these loops must be destroyed in the `beforeDestroy()` component lifecycle hook, otherwise a memory leak occurs.